# Como criar página para cada usuário com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hoje eu vi uma pergunta do usuário marcio.sx sobre criar um sistema de referência, a pergunta foi desativada pois estava com ZERO de detalhes do que ele queria mas eu acredito que peguei a ideia, mas como foi desativada achei interessante criar uma nova pergunta e responder logo abaixo pois acredito que isso possa ajudar muitas pessoas.

A questão é a seguinte:

Como criar um formulário para o usuário pode criar uma página em meu site (meusite.com.br/linkdousuario)?

Além disso como mostrar botões no site onde irão levar para a página desse usuário?

A pergunta estava assim por isso a falta de detalhes fez com que fosse desativada mas abaixo segue uma resposta que talves ajude quem estiver precisando disso.

Eu já tive o mesmo problema há um tempo atrás então fiz essa nova pergunta porém mais específica e vou colocar também uma resposta baseado no que eu fiz no meu caso e conto com outras respostas e métodos diferentes para isso.

Então a pergunta aqui seria:

Como criar uma área em meu site onde usuários cadastrados tivessem uma página de perfil para que outras pessoas pudessem ver seus dados de contato, descrição, foto de perfil e até pontuação por exemplo?

Lembrando que o usuário seria cadastrado no Banco de Dados com os campos necessários mas eu preciso saber como pegar esses dados e apresentar na página do perfil desse usuário (ex. www.meusite.com.br/usuario1).

Uma vez que tiver a resposta sobre como configurar essa página de perfil eu precisaria saber também como ENVIAR as pessoas para lá... por exemplo aqui no site ao clicar no nome de um usuario eu sou enviado para a sua página, seria mais ou menos isso... após configurar a página de perfil como 'linkar' para que as pessoas cheguem até lá?

O site seria uma espécie de Mural de Comentários onde as pessoas fazem um cadastro e então podem participar deixando seus comentários, essa parte está OK eu preciso apenas criar agora a página do perfil e saber como enviar as pessoas para lá.

LEMBRANDO QUE ABAIXO ESTOU COLOCANDO A RESPOSTA E EXPLICANDO DETALHE POR DETALHE ok...

Comment: Se a pergunta foi desativada, é por que ela não estava correta. Reposta-la só vai fazer com que a mesma seja novamente desativada. Se queria ajudar o usuário, poderia ter comentado sobre os problemas com a pergunta e como ele deveria melhorar, e talvez votar negativo... Poderia também procura-lo fora da comunidade ou no chat.

Comment: Olá Leandro, tudo bem? Então, mesmo colando a resposta eu acho que sua pergunta não está clara. Será que poderia adicionar à pergunta alguns detalhes que adicionou na resposta? Assim você poderia conseguir outras respostas de pessoas que pensam diferente de você. É normal em perguntas desse tipo conhecer novas formas de resolver o mesmo problema. xD

Comment: Acho até legal fazer alguma graça como fez na resposta (desde que não seja uma tentativa de ironia, claro), até acho que falta um pouco mais dessa descontração no site. Mas isso não dispensa de melhorar a pergunta. Melhorando a pergunta, aí você vai estar realmente ajudando os outros com a resposta também, e isso é algo a ser incentivado (com votos inclusive). Mas tudo parte da pergunta autosuficiente e completa de maneira a qualquer um com expertise no tema proposto poder responder sem adivinhações. Então, fica a sugestão de [edit] com o que foi pedido, pra ficar tudo legal.

Comment: Na forma atual só o autor pode responder a pergunta por não ser específica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vi que sua pergunta está com poucos detalhes para que possamos ajudá-lo, para que possamos dar a melhor solução para você é necessário ao menos entender finalidade disso que está pedindo... quer criar uma página no seu servidor (salvar um arquivo .PHP nele) ou somente uma página padrão (por exemplo perfil.php) onde o conteúdo será preenchido de acordo com o 'usuário' informado no link?

Eu ACREDITO que o segundo caso é o que você procura, nesse caso você cria uma página onde será preenchida com um conteúdo que está no seu banco, por exemplo:

Ao acessar perfil.php será apresentado uma página inicial com os perfis e botões como você mencionou, e ao clicar em um botão será redirecionado para perfil.php?u=marciosx

Nesse caso a página perfil.php vai verificar que a variável u (de usuário mas você pode colocar qualquer coisa) foi preenchida e vai efetuar uma busca no seu banco de dados.

Aí você deve criar uma tabela com os campos que precisa (nome, nome de usuário, foto, outros conteúdos que deseja) e o site vai pesquisar por exemplo a linha que possui o 'nome de usuário' = 'marciosx' e encontrando essa linha você pode colocar as informações que você deseja no site.

Eu vou deixar abaixo alguns scripts para você mas caso não seja isso que deseja retorne com mais detalhes que assim poderemos ajudá-lo ok. Grande abraço.

```
<!--PRIMEIRO TERÁ QUE FAZER A CONEXAO COM O BANCO CRIANDO A PÁGINA conexao.php QUE ESTÁ ABAIXO-->
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_conexao = "";
$database_conexao = "";
$username_conexao = "";
$password_conexao = "";
$conexao = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conexao, $username_conexao, $password_conexao) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Agora é só incluir a página conexao.php no início ok.

```
<? include('conexao.php'); ?>
```

Depois disso você vai verificar se a variável 'u' foi indicada ou não.

```
<? if(isset($_GET['u'])){<!--Aqui será o código para o caso da variável ter sido indicada-->}

else{<!--Aqui será o código quando não houve variável indicada, ou seja, a página padrão mesmo ou simplesmente um redirecionamento para uma outra página como index.php ou qualquer outra. Aqui vou deixar um redirecionamento para sua página index.php ok-->

echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=index.php'>";
} ?>
```

Bom, como a dúvida é sobre apresentar os dados dos usuários vou direto para essa parte... vamos buscar no banco o usuário marciosx ok.

Isso ficará dentro do campo IF que é o código para quando a variável for indicado que eu comentei acima ok.

```
$usuario = $_GET['u'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perfis WHERE usuario = '$usuario' ");
```

Agora que encontramos eles vamos pegar o conteúdo criado por ele por exemplo, isso você que vai definir pois na pergunta não ficou claro o que será apresentado nesse 'link'.

```
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$nome = $linha['nome']; <!--Aqui pegamos o conteúdo do campo NOME de seu banco e deixamos 'salvo' na $nome. Faça isso para todos os campos como foto, descrição, página do facebook ou qualquer outra coisa que queira apresentar na sua página ok.-->

$foto = $linha['foto'];

$usuario = $linha['usuario'];
    }
```

Bom, agora é só você montar uma página 'padrão' que será praticamente igual para todos os usuários que 'criarem uma página' em seu site, só que o conteúdo será preenchido de acordo com o conteúdo do banco.

Ao colocar uma foto assim:

```
<img src="img/fotodeperfil.jpg" width="100"/>
```

Coloque:

```
<img src="<? echo $foto; ?>" width="100"/>
```

Sendo assim a foto será sempre aquela informada pelo usuário quando 'criou' a página entendeu... o link da foto será salvo no banco junto com o seu nome de usuário, email, descrição, ou qualquer outro conteúdo.

Você pode colocar um valor padrão para o caso do usuário não quiser informar nenhuma foto naquele momento (caso nada seja informado salve img/fotodeperfil.php por exemplo).

Pronto, assim você já consegue pegar através do link o conteúdo da página e montar do jeito que você precisar, agora quanto ao formulário você deverá apenas pegar o conteúdo e salvar no banco, caso não saiba como fazer isso segue abaixo:

```
<form id="cadastro" method="post" action="salvarCadastro.php">
<input name="nome" type="text" />
<input name="usuario" type="text" />
<input name="foto" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Nesse formulário de exemplo pegamos 3 campos (nome, usuário e foto) e agora vamos criar a página salvarCadastro.php para incluir isso no banco, lembrando que precisará da conexão com o banco no início também ok.

```
<?

include('conexao.php');

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO perfis (id, nome, usuario, foto) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",

                       GetSQLValueString("a", "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nome'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['usuario'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['foto'], "text"));





  mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());







echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=index.php?u=". $usuario ."'>";

?>
```

Note que na hora de informar os valores para serem salvos no banco o primeiro está com "a" pois será o ID de seu banco que geralmente é um valor numérico e que é salvo automaticamente pois é a chave primária, então informando "a" o banco vai desconsiderar isso e colocar o próximo número da sequência ok. Sabe criar tabelas no banco né?

Bom... até aqui já temos o formulário para salvar o usuário no banco 'criando sua página'... a página que irá apresentar o conteúdo do usuário e o que falta é somente os botões com o link de cada usuário, isso depende de como você vai fazer, quer abrir uma página com TODOS os usuários do banco?

Aí pode usar o famoso recordset, vou deixar um script seco abaixo (só ajustar para ficar do jeito que vai precisar ok).

```
<?
$maxRows_rsUsuarios = 9999; //Aqui é o limite de resultados que deseja, se colocar 10 serão apresentados somente os 10 primeiros (ou últimos dependendo da forma que definir) resultados.

$pageNum_rsUsuarios = 0; // Se precisar paginar sugiro pesquisar um pouco mais sobre isso para fazer de forma adequada ou fazer uma nova pergunta no site.

if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rsUsuarios'])) {

  $pageNum_rsUsuarios = $_GET['pageNum_rsUsuarios'];

}

$startRow_rsUsuarios = $pageNum_rsUsuarios * $maxRows_rsUsuarios;



mysql_select_db($database_conexaomural, $conexaomural);

$query_rsUsuarios = "SELECT * FROM perfis ORDER BY id DESC"; //Aqui eu defini a ordem por ID - ou seja, ordem que as páginas foram criadas - sendo que pode colocar a ordem do mais novo para mais antigo ou o inverso (DESC ou ASC). Assim está o mais novo primeiro ok. Você pode ordenar por nome em ordem alfabetica também, fazendo assim (ORDER BY usuario ASC)

$query_limit_rsUsuarios = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rsUsuarios, $startRow_rsUsuarios, $maxRows_rsUsuarios);

$rsUsuarios = mysql_query($query_limit_rsUsuarios, $conexaomural) or die(mysql_error());

$row_rsUsuarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsUsuarios);



if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rsUsuarios'])) {

  $totalRows_rsUsuarios = $_GET['totalRows_rsUsuarios'];

} else {

  $all_rsUsuarios = mysql_query($query_rsUsuarios);

  $totalRows_rsUsuarios = mysql_num_rows($all_rsUsuarios);

}

$totalPages_rsUsuarios = ceil($totalRows_rsUsuarios/$maxRows_rsUsuarios)-1;



$queryString_rsUsuarios = "";

if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

  $newParams = array();

  foreach ($params as $param) {

    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_rsUsuarios") == false && 

        stristr($param, "totalRows_rsUsuarios") == false) {

      array_push($newParams, $param);

    }

  }

  if (count($newParams) != 0) {

    $queryString_rsUsuarios = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));

  }

}

$queryString_rsUsuarios = sprintf("&totalRows_rsUsuarios=%d%s", $totalRows_rsUsuarios, $queryString_rsUsuarios);
?>
```

Agora que o código já pegou todos os usuários do banco é só você escolher o local do site que eles vão aparecer... pode colocar isso em uma lista (que pode ser muito extensa dependendo da quantidade de cadastro então vai precisar usar paginação) ou até usar uma div para ir rolando, usando o overflow scroll onde todos os resultados ficarão dentro dela e o usuário poderá ir rolando os resultados, se abrir o WhatsApp Web verá que as últimas conversas ficam fixas no canto esquerdo da tela e você apoia o mouse ali e rola pra baixo mexendo somente o que está dentro daquela div sem afetar o restante da página, seria mais ou menos isso, mas não precisa ser fixo nem no canto esquerdo, pode colocar em qualquer local da página que quiser, por exemplo.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:350px; height:550px; border:1px solid #F2F2F2">

</div>
```

Agora vamos colocar dentro dessa div o conteúdo com TODOS os usuários do banco ok.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:350px; height:550px; border:1px solid #F2F2F2">

<?php do { ?>
<!--NESSE TRECHO FICARÁ A REPETIÇÃO DE TODOS OS CADASTROS OK-->
<?php } while ($row_rsUsuarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsUsuarios)); ?>

</div>
```

O codigo para repetição é esse acima agora vamos montar um exemplo ok:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:350px; height:550px; border:1px solid #F2F2F2">

<?php do { ?>

<div style="width:300px; margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="middle">
<td width="120" align="left">
<img src="<?php echo $row_rsUsuarios['foto']; ?>" width="100" />
</td>
<td>
Usuário: <?php echo $row_rsUsuarios['usuario']; ?> - <a href="perfil.php?<?php echo $row_rsUsuarios['usuario']; ?>">Clique aqui</a> para acessar a página desse usuário.
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>



<?php } while ($row_rsUsuarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsUsuarios)); ?>

</div>
```

É isso, o formulário salva os dados 'criando a página' do usuário, o código acima mostra TODOS os usuários que possuem uma 'página' em seu site e ao clicar no link será aberto a página perfil.php já informando a variável "u" que seria a página daquele usuário ok.

Agora é só adaptar o código com os dados que você precisa e montar isso dentro do seu site (não me preocupei com aparência é claro, coloquei o código seco ok, aí você vai montando de forma bacana com um bom layout).

Espero ter ajudado e espero que seja isso mesmo que você esteva procurando.